# I have a TypeError in React and my app won't load because of this error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'title' of 'collection' as it is undefined

```
const CollectionPage = ({ collection }) => {

    const { title, items } = collection;
    
    return (
    <div className='collection-page'>
    <h2 className='title'>{ title }</h2>
    <div className='items'>
        {
           items.map(item => ( 
        <CollectionItem key={item.id} item={item} />
           ))}
      </div>
    </div>
)};
```

Comment: This means in `<CollectionPage collection={ /* here */} />` the value is `undefined`.

Comment: How do I fix this error? @norbitrial

Comment: Can you please share the usage of that component and how you are passing `collection` there? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can solve this

one way is to have a placeholder text / empty items array

```
const { title, items } = collection || { title: "Default", items: [] }
```

second way is a loading indicator

```
if(!collection  || !Object.keys(collection).length) return "Loading..."
```